# Predict colours

Tags: regression, probability, predictive-models, measurement-error, mode

I have very basic knowledge in statistical science and appreciate your patience. My problem is if you have a bag with seven differently coloured balls, you are allowed to blindly pick 3 balls every minute, and you do this for 3 minutes (like three times). What can I use to make accurate, as possible, predictions on what are the colours of the picked balls each time?

Comment: Do you pick balls with or without replacement?

Comment: By that, the question is if, after you pick that first of three balls, do you put that ball back in the bag and select from all seven balls, or do you select from the remaining six? Likewise, what happens when you go to select your third ball? Are you drawing from five or seven balls (or even six, if you have an unusual but still possible replacement strategy)? // Also, do you have any information besides how many balls of each color are in the bag?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Ricardo. This is such an artificial situation that you should excuse us for believing that your problem is something different.  Rather than using a vaguely described metaphor like pulling balls from a bag, please consider describing what your *real* problem is.  That helps us focus on what matters and avoids the pain of giving good answers to the wrong question.